# How to query MongoDB array to see if it has multiple instances of same $elemMatch?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection where each document has an array (called `elements`) in it. Each element within this array represents an object with a `name` and `age` value. I have some documents where in the array, I will have duplicate objects, or at least objects with some similar values (i.e. the `name` is the same).

My collection looks like this (notice how the 2nd document has 2 instances of `Bob`):

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "6395471f80495752e7208c63"
    },
    "elements": [
      {
        "name": "Alice",
        "age": 20
      },
      {
        "name": "Bob",
        "age": 21
      },
      {
        "name": "Charlie",
        "age": 23
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "6395486980495752e7208c67"
    },
    "elements": [
      {
        "name": "Alice",
        "age": 20
      },
      {
        "name": "Bob",
        "age": 21
      },
      {
        "name": "Bob",
        "age": 24
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to be able to build a query with `$elemMatch` so that if I want to, I can find a document which has multiple instances of the same `$elemMatch` element, i.e. I want to be able to find a document which has an `elements` array with 2 Bob's in it.

I have tried doing a query like the one below, but with no success.

```
db.collection.find({
  $and: [
    {
      elements: {
        $elemMatch: {
          name: "Bob"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      elements: {
        $elemMatch: {
          name: "Bob"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

The intended result of this query would be as follows:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("6395486980495752e7208c67"),
    "elements": [
      {
        "age": 20,
        "name": "Alice"
      },
      {
        "age": 21,
        "name": "Bob"
      },
      {
        "age": 24,
        "name": "Bob"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here is a [MongoPlayground link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XZH4jNj3G36) which may make the problem easier to view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current attempt does not instruct the database to find two different array elements which match the (same) condition. The second array entry in the first sample document is allowed to satisfy both of the (duplicated) conditions that are `$and`ed together, hence it matching and being returned.

To instruct the database to do that additional checking, we'll need to use something like the `$reduce` operator. Typically these were available in the aggregation framework, but we can pull them in here via `$expr`. That component of the query might look like this:

```
  $expr: {
    $gte: [
      {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$elements",
          initialValue: 0,
          in: {
            $sum: [
              "$$value",
              {
                $cond: [
                  {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$this.name",
                      "Bob"
                    ]
                  },
                  1,
                  0
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      2
    ]
  }
```

[Playground example here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/u8z0ef3m-U6).

A different approach would be to use `$size` *after* processing the `elements` array via `$filter`. Something like this:

```
  $expr: {
    $gte: [
      {
        $size: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$elements",
            cond: {
              $eq: [
                "$$this.name",
                "Bob"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      2
    ]
  }
```

[Example playground here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SqLmsE2OQNv).

In either case you will want to retain the original filter so that the database can more efficiently identify candidate documents prior to doing the more expensive processing to identify the final results.

As an aside, `$elemMatch` isn't strictly necessary here. Assuming `elements` is always an array and that you're only [querying a single condition](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#single-query-condition), the dot notation equivalent (`'elements.name': 'Bob'`) would yield the same as the `$elemMatch` version.

Comment: Thanks for both ways of going about the solution! Do you know if either route is more efficient than the other?

Also regarding your aside point, I oversimplified my actual data/query for the sake of this question, in my actual use case there are multiple datapoints I am querying on

Comment: I'm not sure if either approach will short circuit instead of processing the entire array. Although it's longer and perhaps a little less readable, personally I think I'd have a slight preference for the `$reduce` approach